# How to run a python script from clicking a button on a HTML webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I currently have a python script that updates certain CSV files when ran (it web scrapes and updates the information of a CSV file). In my HTML page (index.html), I have a script tag inside index.html that reads the CSV file and displays it as a table on the webpage. However, what I now need to do is update the CSV file by pressing an HTML button on the webpage. This will update the CSV file so when I run the button to run the JS script, it will have updated values from the file.

I searched and found it very hard to understand what they meant by using flask and Django (I don't know anything about setting up servers). I don't want to set up a Django webpage because I want to work with my current pure HTML webpage I wrote.

I would appreciate it if the answer is up to date with the current standard solutions for running python scripts in HTML.

Please ask if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: A browser won't run python. You'll need a server. Or rewrite the python to javascript to run all in the browser

Comment: So I supposed to call the server inside the HTML to the python script on the server?

Comment: You can use [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) or [`flask`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) (which is actually pretty simple, the minimal example has 5 lines of code). Then you can post to that webserver and react accordingly.

Comment: @a_guest Okay but how would I be able to call flask or its server inside HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup a web server. [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) can be used for that purpose. So you can create the following script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, redirect, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    with open('index.html') as fh:
        return fh.read()

@app.route('/update')
def update_file():
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
    return redirect(request.referrer)
```

The `@app.route('/')` provides your landing page which is stored in `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/update">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML page contains a submit button which refers to `/update`. In the web server script above this route is registered with the `update_file` function. Here you can implement your logic to react to the button press (in the example it writes the current time to `data.txt` *on the server*). Since the script operates on the server and your browser operates on the client this only works if that is actually the same machine, i.e. if your using it locally as an interface to your programs. If you want to separate server and client you'll need to introduce a way for transferring the data.

Now you can run the web server as follows:

```
$ FLASK_APP=script.py flask run
[...]
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Now you can navigate to the address indicates above and you'll be on the landing page. Pressing the button updates the file:

```
$ tree .
.
├── data.txt    <-- This file gets updated.
├── index.html
├── __pycache__
│   └── script.cpython-38.pyc
└── script.py
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, this works. However, when I click the button, it changes to a blank page with address: http://127.0.0.1:5000/update?. Would you know how I can stay on the original index.html after clicking the button?

Comment: @user12055579 You can `return redirect(request.referrer)` instead of an empty string. Please see my updated example (imports have changed too).

Comment: Oh, yes! Perfect, thanks! One last question, how would I be able to change the address: i.e. http://127.0.0.1:5000/ to a website address (if I had a website with a web host setup etc.)

Comment: @user12055579 That should be the address where the web server runs. It really depends where it is hosted (i.e. the URL of your website).

Comment: How do I change the webserver i.e. run it on something else than http://127.0.0.1:5000/?

Comment: @user12055579 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You need to host it somewhere, e.g. https://www.heroku.com/. 127.0.0.1 means it's hosted on your local machine.

Comment: Okay, so how I would I be able to change the host?

Comment: @user12055579 As I mentioned you need to host it somewhere. You need to choose the host. There are many options, as I mentioned heroku.com is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run python in html. You can just use javascript. but you can pass the information as json and then use javascript if you don't want to change the language or using python frameworks.

Comment: Okay, I wouldn't mind python frameworks inside HTML, but I am not sure how to call it inside the HTML webpage? Do I use JavaScript for that?

Comment: Yes, I know. What I meant in my question is that I am not totally sure on how to use them (because of servers) but I wouldn't mind using them. I also don't want to completely make a new HTML webpage using Django.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use them inside another project. You should build up a project based on django. If you are not in the middle of a project based on JS you can try the documentation of django and it's not going to take much time to finish it. but if you are not intending on learning django I recommend using json for your outputs of python (and it's not hard because you could get CSV)